# Is there an idiom for "I know you have good intention, but we need to stick to the rule"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom for "I know you have good intention, but we need to stick to the rule"?

Comment: I don't think this is quite what you mean, but "[the road to hell is paved with good intentions](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+road+to+hell+is+paved+with+good+intentions)".

Comment: What it actually nets down to is *You **mean** well, but you're **stupid*** (cleverer people than you devised the rules that we need to stick to).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Won't that be rude? Calling someone stupid right on their face?

Comment: Well yes. But the fact of the matter is the speaker doesn't think whatever the addressee wants to do is a good idea, or he wouldn't be reminding him that we need to stick to the rules (presumably the addressee doesn't want to stick to the rules). However you dress it up, *Yes, you mean well. But you're **wrong**!*

Comment: "Don't wear your heart on your sleeve"

Comment: @TylerM What?  That's totally different.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that would be a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“The ends don’t justify the means”. Whether or not you agree with the sentiment philosophically/morally, the meaning of the phrase is that you shouldn’t do something wrong in order to accomplish something good.

Comment: That works for an ethical rule, but not for a safety rule.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiom given by [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+road+to+hell+is+paved+with+good+intentions)

> **The road to hell is paved with good intentions**

There are several slants on its meaning

- You can makes matters worse by interfering and good intentions alone are not enough.
- There might be unforseen collateral damage unrelated to the situation.
- People often intend to do good things but do not, because they are lazy or weak.
- You can get yourself in trouble if you think the ends justify the means – @[Alex](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265212/56820).

Whether any of these fit the actual question

> I know you have good intention, but we need to stick to the rule

might depend on the context, but the idiom could be used to put someone off an idea that is unrealistic – @[FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265186/is-there-an-idiom-for-i-know-you-have-good-intention-but-we-need-to-stick-to-t?noredirect=1#comment495645_265186).